# How to execute script in new Terminal tab, not in new window?

Tags: bash, terminal, sh, expect

I have an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script saved as `my_file.sh` on my desktop. Script works just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh name@my.domain.com
expect "assword:"
...
```

I have a Terminal open. When I double click `my_file.sh` on my desktop, the new Terminal window is open. How can I force this script to open a new Terminal **tab** instead?

Comment: what operating system are you using first of all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Given that you're using OS X I think you need a solution that involves applescript + bash.**

- You need to open up Apple Script Editor ( cmd + spacebar )
- Paste the following code into the editor:

> ```
> tell application "Terminal"
>       activate
>       tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal.app" to keystroke "t" using command down
>       do script "cd ~/Desktop/ && bash ./my_file.sh" in front window
> end tell
> ```

- Save this script as an Application ( see screenshot ):

  [image: Picture of Applescript]
- Make sure you have your my_file.sh setup correctly with your bash scripts and it will open up the Terminal app, make your tab, and run your command for you.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: hi Malcolm. I've saved your script as `test.sh`. When I double click on it, it opens a new Terminal window and then in that new Terminal window it opens a new tab, which defeats the purpose. Please advise for a solution.

Comment: @Prosak: Couple questions to make sure I understand everything well, 1. Was Terminal.app open at all to begin with? 2. You simply want it to open up your script in a new tab correct? or do you just want a window that will run my_file.sh? - When I understand correctly I will update my answer.

Comment: 1) Yes, the Terminal was already running. But execution of `test.sh` opened a <b>second</b> window and then tab in it. 2) Yes, I want it to open a new tab inside already running Terminal window and execute code in it.

Comment: @Prostak one last question which could explain why all this might be happening, for OS X, what is your default application used to run your .sh scripts? Here are my defaults now: http://imgur.com/bzJQl7d What do yours show?

Comment: @Prostak Okay, I know what to do. I'm about to update my answer.